# Is Java DMK (or OpenDMK) still supported by Oracle?

Tags: java, jdmk, opendmk

Is Java DMK (Dynamic Management Kit) still supported by Oracle? I was trying to find any reference to JDMK on Oracle's site and all I could find was documentation/tutorial on how to use it, no reference to the product page itself.

I know about OpenDMK, but that too seems to not have developed past 2007. I am trying to migrate from Jingle JMXRemote to the newer Cascading API and didn't want to start using more redundant technology.

Comment: I'd say "not developped since 2007" is pretty much the same as "not supported".

Comment: @millimouse -   Counter-example. You can get an Oracle support contract for old versions of Java. I don't know how far back, but a long way.  There hasn't been any new development on these versions for a long time, but I think that Oracle is (at least) applying patches for critical security issues.  Which is why people are prepared to pay for support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "supported".  If you want support in the normal sense, you should contact the Oracle support folks and ask them.  However, given that JDMK doesn't appear to be listed as an Oracle product any more, I think that the answer is likely to be "No".

If you are really asking if there is any likelihood of further development of JDMK or OpenJDMK, I'd say that it looks pretty unlikely<sup>1</sup>.  Your best bet would be to ask Daniel Fuchs directly ... using the contact information on the openjdmk project site.

However, the fact that JDMK / OpenJDMK project is "in a coma" as far as new work is concerned doesn't imply that the technology is "redundant".  It is up to you to judge whether it is "fresh" enough for your requirements ... relative to other ways of meeting them.

---

<sup>1 - This is clearly a non-objective statement; i.e. just my opinion.</sup>

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Thanks for the rollback!